# Pipenv installed git package not importable

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pipenv

I'm using pipenv (version 2018.11.26, Python 3.6.0) to install a package I've created and pushed on a private github repo.

The package contains a setup.py file with the following content:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='testlib',
    version='0.0.1',
    desctiption='Hello py packaging',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

I install the package in a virtualenv with

```
pipenv install  git+https://<token>@github.<private-repo>/<subdir>/testlib.git#egg=testlib
> Successfully installed testlib-0.0.1
```

and check if it has been installed correctly

```
$ pip freeze | grep testlib
> testlib==0.0.1
```

But if I try to import the module, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`

```
(.venv) pipenv_tests>python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testlib'
>>>
```

Can anyone help me understand why?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My bad, the folder structure was wrong!

setup.py has to be outside the package folder:

```
repo_folder
|_ setup.py
|_ testlib
|__ classa.py
|__ classb.py
```

where setup.py (as mentioned in the question) is

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='testlib',
    version='0.0.1',
    desctiption='Hello py packaging',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Now if I import the package, it works!!!

```
(.venv) pipenv_tests>python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:06:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testlib
>>> _
```